# How to install Full-text search into SQL Server 2016?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, full-text-search

I tried to use full-text search in Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Express edition (installed with Visual Studio 2017). When I tried to create a FULLTEXT CATALOG, I got an error

> Cannot use full-text search in user instance.

Then I was run

```
select fulltextserviceproperty('isfulltextinstalled')
```

and got '0' result. Does anybody know how install it?

Comment: Well - the error already tells you **cannot use full-text search** - as in: you **cannot** use FTS in an **Express** edition  if you use the so-called "user instance" feature (specifying the `.mdf` file in your connection string). So you cannot "install" it - it's just not available. You need to use a **server-based** database model - not fiddling around with free-floating `.mdf` files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using LocalDB, which doesn't support it.

Full-text indexing is supported on Express with Advanced Services and "better", [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2016 - Programmability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017#Programmability):

```
Feature                           Enterprise     Standard     Web     Express with Advanced Services     Express
Full-text and semantic search     Yes            Yes          Yes     Yes                                No
```

You will need to use Express with Advanced Services, rather than LocalDB if you want to use Full-text Searching.